# Tailwind - how to set default text color in React Native

Tags: react-native, tailwind-css

Im building a project in react native and tailwind. For every text component, I am passing "text-black".

```
<Text style={tailwind('text-black')}> Hi </Text>
```

Can I set the default color for text component to be black somewhere to overcome this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create a custom component that wraps the Text component and applies the default style you want.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

const DefaultText = ({ style, children }) => (
  <Text style={[tailwind('text-black'), style]}>{children}</Text>
);

export default DefaultText;
```

Now, whenever you want to use a Text component and have it automatically be styled with the default color, just use the DefaultText component instead.